# Sync SQL Server metadata in Access?

Tags: sql, sql-server, ms-access

I'm trying to set up a quick Access database to track business requirements and transformation rules for an ETL process in SQL Server. Is there a way for me to sync Access with the info schema in SQL Server -- so that I can pull in the source and target table names and column names without having to type them over again? I want to be able to tag requirements and transformation rules with the columns involved.

Or....is there an easier way to do this? How do people normally track and preserve this stuff?

Comment: I guess you want sth like this, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/stored-procedures/create-a-stored-procedure?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: What do you mean with _Sync_? You can just pull data from the _INFORMATION_SCHEMA_ tables using a pass-through query.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should get you pointed in the right direction.

```
#1)  ODBC Database (create link to SQL Server)

#2)  Open the link and view your Information_Schema in SQL Server.
```

[image]

[image]